# View the contents and constraints of a table

Tags: oracle

I am working on this assignment question and it is asking me:

1. To create a table called (`TEMP_CUST`) from an existing table `Customers`
2. View the content and constraints of `TEMP_CUST` table

What I have done so far is I have created my table, didn't add any constraints to the table `TEMP_CUST` and viewed the table using the `DESC` command.

Here is the code for table creation

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_CUST 
AS 
    (SELECT 
         CUSTOMER#, LASTNAME, 
         FIRSTNAME, ADDRESS, CITY, 
         STATE, ZIP, REFERRED, 
         REGION, EMAIL 
     FROM 
         CUSTOMERS);

DESC TEMP_CUST;
```

Now that I have done that I want to view the constraints of the table. I have used this command but am not sure if it is correct.

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TEMP_CUST';
```

Comment: yes, but it is still the same right.?

Comment: Why do you think it's not correct? What is actually puzzling you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i have used this command, but not sure if it is correct.

You haven't said why you don't think it's correct so we have to guess the reason for your doubt. Perhaps it's because the set of constraints you get is smaller than the set of constraints for the original CUSTOMERS table?

That is correct. When we use CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT the statement creates a new table with the projection, column names and datatypes of the original tables (assuming a vanilla SELECT clause) and the data (determined by the WHERE clause, if any). However, the only constraints which are created are NOT NULL constraints on the primary key column(s) and any other mandatory columns. The new table does not have primary key, foreign key or check constraints. We have to create these explicitly.

Hence, this query ...

```
SELECT * FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TEMP_CUST';
```

... might return fewer constraints than you were expecting.